# grunt-copy-deps does not copy dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs

`Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    copydeps: {
        target: {
            options: {
                unminified: true,
                css: true
            },
            pkg: 'package.json',
            dest: 'src/main/webapp/libs/'
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-copy-deps');


// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['copydeps']);
};
```

I am expecting (being a total noob) that it'll copy everything from node_modules that is mentioned in `package.json` as non-development dependencies, to my webapp directory. Here's the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "coll-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "keywords": [
    "util",
    "functional",
    "server",
    "client",
    "browser"
  ],
  "author": "fedd",
  "contributors": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "bpmn-js": "0.26.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "1.0.0",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-copy-deps": "1.2.2"
  }
}
```

But the `webapp/libs/` doesnot appear and files are not copied. Here's the grunt verbosities when run from commandline:

```
# grunt -v
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-copy-deps" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/fedd/Documents/Work/NetBeansProjects/coll/node_modules/grunt-copy-deps/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/fedd/Documents/Work/NetBeansProjects/coll/node_modules/grunt-copy-deps/package.json...OK
Loading "copydeps.js" tasks...OK
+ copydeps
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ default

No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default

Running "default" task

Running "copydeps" task

Running "copydeps:target" (copydeps) task
Verifying property copydeps.target exists in config...OK
Files: -> src/main/webapp/libs/
Options: minified, unminified, js, css, ignore=[], exclude={"css":[],"js":[]}, include={"css":{},"js":{}}
Reading /home/fedd/Documents/Work/NetBeansProjects/coll/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/fedd/Documents/Work/NetBeansProjects/coll/package.json...OK

Done.
```

What's happening and why doesn't it copy anything?

I also run this from Netbeans 8.2 with no luck. Other versions:

```
# nodejs --version
v8.9.4
# npm --version
5.6.0
# grunt --version
grunt-cli v1.2.0
# ubuntu --version
ubuntu: command not found
```

actually, 17.10. Thanks!

Comment: I think your assumption that _"...it'll copy everything from node_modules that is mentioned in `package.json` as non-development dependencies"_ is correct - based on the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-copy-deps). Also, there is nothing wrong with your `Gruntfile.js` configuration as far I can tell. Having just tried using this package myself I also could not get any files to copy using various configurations. I'd be inclined to log an issue in the  [projects repo](https://github.com/laurenhamel/grunt-copy-deps).

Comment: @RobC thanks for your time... the documentation was promising... probably I've found another non-trivial way to do some common thing. If you have another spare second, do you know how people normally move dependencies around for a front-end projects? without minifying etc, going to employ RequireJS. "node_modules" is an ugly directory name, in my Netbeans IDE it resides in project root only, and contains too much development dependencies.. =(

Comment: Typically, people dont’t move dependencies  as it’s likely to break the project. The `node_modules` directory typically resides in the project root directory. It’s quite common practice to add  the `node_modules` directory to your [.gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) to avoid copying to a git repo. If someone  downloads the project they run [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)  to install  dependencies as per   `package.json`. Assuming your `package.json` is correct you can delete the `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` to reinstate them.